# Got "Maximum call stack size exceeded" with Vue using ChartJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-chartjs

I want to pass the data from Parent to GrandChild (which is Chart) with reactivity so I'm using props.

> This is the **Parent**

The "kalkulator-data" component below is worked and it's used to adding data to **Parent**.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

                <kalkulator-data 
                    :saldoAwal="saldoAwal" 
                    :saldoTerpakai="saldoTerpakai" 
                    :saldoAkhir="saldoAkhir"
                    :dataKategori="dataKategori"
                    :dataPengeluaran="dataPengeluaran"

                    @inputSaldo="saldoAwal = $event"
                    @inputPengeluaran="dataPengeluaran.push($event)">

                </kalkulator-data>

                <kalkulator-chart
                    :chartData="chartData"
                    :chartOptions="chartOptions">    

                </kalkulator-chart>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Chart from './Bagian/Chart.vue';
    import Data from './Bagian/Data.vue';

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                saldoAwal : 0,
                dataPengeluaran : [{ kategori : 'Abi', nominal : 12}, { kategori : 'Ilham', nominal : 13}],
                dataKategori : [
                    'Makan dan Minum',
                    'Berbelanja',
                    'Perlengkapan Rumah',
                    'Transportasi',
                    'Kendaraan',
                    'Gaya Hidup dan Hiburan',
                    'Komunikasi',
                    'Pengeluaran dan Finansial',
                    'Investasi',
                ],
                chartOptions : {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false}
            }
        },
        computed : {
            saldoTerpakai(){
                var saldoPakai = 0;
                for(var data of this.dataPengeluaran){
                    saldoPakai += parseInt(data.nominal);
                }
                return saldoPakai;
            },
            saldoAkhir(){
                return this.saldoAwal - this.saldoTerpakai;
            },
            getRandomColor(){
                var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
                var color = '#';
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
                }
                return color;
            },
            chartLabels(){
                var chartLabels = [];
                for (var data of this.dataPengeluaran ){
                    chartLabels.push(data.kategori);
                    // backgroundColor.push(this.getRandomColor);
                };
                return chartLabels;
            },
            chartId(){
                var chartData = [];
                for (var data of this.dataPengeluaran ){
                    chartData.push(parseInt(data.nominal));
                    // backgroundColor.push(this.getRandomColor);
                };
                return chartData;
            },
            chartData(){
                return {
                    labels: this.chartLabels,
                    datasets: [
                      {
                        label: 'Data One',
                        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
                        data: this.chartId
                      }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        methods : {

        },
        components : {
            'kalkulator-data' : Data,
            'kalkulator-chart' : Chart
        },
    }
</script>
```

> This is the **Child**

```
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="text-center">Struktur Pengeluaran</h1>

            <chart-comp 
                :chartData="chartData"
                :chartOptions="chartOptions">               
            </chart-comp>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import chartComp from './Chart-Data.js'

    export default{
        props : ['chartData', 'chartOptions'],
        components : {
            'chart-comp' : chartComp
        }
    }
</script>
```

> And this the **GrandChild** which is Chart

```
import {Bar} from 'vue-chartjs'

export default Bar.extend({
    props : ['chartData', 'chartOptions'],
    computed : {
        renderChart(){
            this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions);
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.renderChart;
    }
})
```

I'm using computed to keep the reactivity when I'm added data, but It said in console :

```
app.js:5366 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

found in

---> <ChartComp>
       <KalkulatorChart> at C:\xampp\htdocs\SemuaOkee-Laravel\resources\assets\js\components\Bagian\Chart.vue
         <Kalkulator> at C:\xampp\htdocs\SemuaOkee-Laravel\resources\assets\js\components\Kalkulator.vue
           <Root>
warn @ app.js:5366
handleError @ app.js:5451
callHook @ app.js:7490
insert @ app.js:8315
invokeInsertHook @ app.js:10143
patch @ app.js:10308
Vue._update @ app.js:7248
updateComponent @ app.js:7371
get @ app.js:7710
Watcher @ app.js:7693
mountComponent @ app.js:7375
Vue$3.$mount @ app.js:12503
Vue$3.$mount @ app.js:14602
Vue._init @ app.js:8942
Vue$3 @ app.js:9027
(anonymous) @ app.js:29926
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:29888
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:63
(anonymous) @ app.js:66
app.js:5455 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Watcher.evaluate (app.js:7809)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as renderChart] (app.js:8064)
    at VueComponent.renderChart (app.js:61047)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:7710)
    at Watcher.evaluate (app.js:7810)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as renderChart] (app.js:8064)
    at VueComponent.renderChart (app.js:61047)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:7710)
    at Watcher.evaluate (app.js:7810)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as renderChart] (app.js:8064)
```

When I'm still not added the data, it's work perfectly ( that's why I'm hardcoded two objects in **Parent** to test my Chart in the beginning), but when I'm added a data it's got an error.

In other words, It's work on static but not with dynamic data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your grandchild component, you have defined a computed property `renderChart` which returns `this.renderChart`. This is what is causing the Maximum call stack size error.

You should just call the `renderChart` method in the `mounted` hook:

```
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default Bar.extend({
    props: ['chartData', 'chartOptions'],
    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions);
    }
})
```

---

If you need the chart data to be reactive, vue-chartjs provides an admittedly goofy way to specify that using a mixin:

```
import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default Bar.extend({
    props: ['chartData', 'chartOptions'],
    mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions);
    }
})
```

[Here's the vue-chartjs documentation on using reactive data.](http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=reactive-data)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's result in inreactivity (which mean when I'm adding data to parent, the chart doesn't change). That's why I'm decided to using computed (but got an error)

Comment: @IlhamWahabi vue-chartjs makes you use a mixin to specify that you want the data to be reactive. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error in vue.js when rendering a component, you have to destroy the Chart before refilling the value, you can do it as I did below:

```js
<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js';
export default {
  name: 'card',
  props: {
  chartData: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
},
mounted() {
    this.createChart('planet-chart', this.chartData);
},
data() {
    return {
        myChart: null
    }
},
methods:{
    createChart(chartId, chartData) {
        const ctx = document.getElementById(chartId);
        this.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: chartData.type,
            data: chartData.data,
            options: chartData.options,
        });
    }
},
beforeDestroy() {
   if(this.myChart) {
        this.myChart.destroy();
    } 
 }
};
</script>
```